# Element with max-height based on the height of the viewport. Image within should scale and keep ratio

Tags: html, css, scale, viewport

Looking for a way to make sure that the height of an `article` element is never greater than 65% of the viewport height. Also there's an image nested inside the element that must be contained to the height of it's parent and be able to scaledown to the max-height and keep the it's ratio (yes, the image should be fully visible, no cropping).

It's also important that `img` and the overlaying div `.actions` have the same width at all times.
Is this possible with css only?

This is just a test case, there's other elements like this, the markup is the same, but the ratio of the element within each element is unique.

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/SpPDp/show/

**Code**
http://jsfiddle.net/SpPDp/

**Source below**

```
<article>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="text">Text</div>
                <div class="yep">Yep</div>
                <div class="heretoo">Here too</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-g-600-900-4.jpg">                        
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

```
article {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

article .inner {
   position: relative;
}

article .overlay {
   position: absolute;
   background: #000;
   opacity: 0.7;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

article .actions {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1%;
   width: 100%;
   color: #fff;
   background: red;
}

.text {
   float: left;
}

.yep {
    display: inline-block;
}

.heretoo {
   float: right;
}

article img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `<article>` is variable height (not fixed at 65% height)?

Comment: @TylerH Correct. It varies, but should be restricted to be no greater than 65% of VP.

Comment: do the images always have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: INT, if there's still anything wrong with my answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say that the ability to change even the tiniest part of your html would make it so much easy to accomplish the result.

For example, setting the image as `background`, and accepting the fact that it should be cropped, would make the task a no-brainer.

But you make it clear that:

- Articles must be max 65% of viewport h;
- The meta bar over it should always have the same width as the image;
- Images must not be cropped nor distorted.

If your question is formulated correctly, which I really hope it is, since we are all trying to solve it, you imply that **articles widths won't always be equal**.

The solution is to let the image figure out what is best to do. First, we set it's max-size in `vw` and `vh`, then we clear the way of unwanted positionings and sizes, to allow the size of the image to go up to the container, then back down to the meta bar in the overlay. Also, notice the use of flex boxes.

## Here's the CSS (I didn't touch the HTML)

```
article {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.inner {
  /* older browsers. you should add the other prefixes too. there are polyfills to have broader support, check link later in the answer */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -moz-box-direction: reverse;
  -ms-box-direction: reverse;
  box-direction: reverse;
  
  /* newer */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* the meta box is added
after the image container, and the items are arranged in column */


}

.overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 0 -25px; /* magic: this cuts the container by 25px (height of meta bar) */
}

.actions {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(200,0,0,0.8);

  /* older */ 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify; /* distribute the labels */
  -moz-box-pack: justify; 
  -ms-box-pack: justify; 
  box-pack: justify; 
  -webkit-box-direction: normal; /* reset order (it used to be inherited) */
  -moz-box-direction: normal; 
  -ms-box-direction: normal; 
  box-direction: normal; 
  
  /* newer */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* distribute the labels */
  -moz-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  /* move up */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-25px);  
  -moz-transform: translate(0,-25px);  
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-25px);  
  transform: translate(0,-25px);  
  
  box-shadow: 0 -1000px 0 1030px rgba(0,0,0,.6); /* since it
can't actually know the size, the overlay is accomplished with
a shadow. as long as it is not blurred, it won't impact
performances much */
  font-size: 1.4vw; /* the only hard limit now is the width
of the text */
}

.content {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  /* commenting those 2 last properties has two effects in webkit. 1) it avoids the images to stretch. 2) when you resize your window, the images won't adapt. only on load/refresh. this should be ok though, as window resizing is not really what responsive is most useful for
  --- old code ---
  display: -webkit-box;  
  display: -ms-box; 
  display: -moz-box; 
  display: box; 
   --- new code --- 
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;  */

}

.content img {
  max-width: 40vw; /* and here you finally set the sizes.
note that you can set a min-width too, if you want, but
if you do there will be some image ratio that will force
them to stretch */
  max-height: 65vh;
}
```

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/NssKa/

The result, with many images of different ratios: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/NssKa/embedded/result/

Off course, this is just theory and is a valid answer to your question.

If you want to use this in production you should add some good polyfill for the older browsers, perhaps you could add [this polyfill](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie). As you can see I have already added the older box model properties as fallback.

Comment: Wow! I had already lost hope, but it seems you've been able to solve some off the stuff here. I'm on Safari 6.0.5 so the flex is not working properly. For some reason 1600x600 is stretched out. I also tried to set `bottom: 0` to `.actions` but it makes them fall outside the boxes. Might be because of Safari 6 aswell. I'll tinker some more!

Comment: just add the older model to the mix, like i said in the answer.. editing the code to show you how. please let me know if it works in safari 6 too, but i think that you should edit your question to specify that this is about safari 6 because things changed in the meanwhile!

Comment: also added a negative margin to the overlay container to trim the articles container by 25px.

Comment: Been really busy at work so haven't been able to test this out just yet, but as you've put tremendous of work into this I'll award you the bounty, so it doesn't run out. I'll post a comment here if I find something that's unclear. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Thank you, feel free to ask more :)

Comment: I've had some chance to play around with this now. I've found that it works very well in Firefox, but with Safari and Chrome the images are streched or compressed in ways that destroys the aspect ratio. Have you had any trouble? Typically if you remove either max-height or max-width it will maintain aspect again, but then it's back to square one again..

Comment: Seems fine in Safari (7.0.3), but you're right that there were issues in Chrome. I removed the `display flex` property from the image, now the images aren't stretching anymore, but there's what seems to be a bug in webkit: if you manually resize the window the changes are going to be picked only on refresh. I think it's a thing I can live with, since window resizing is not the primary goal of responsive. I will look further into the issue, though. Please let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/NssKa/

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion. I'm still seeing problem in Safari 6.0.5. The height is constrained for some reason. If I remove vw max-width, the aspect is kept again. Edit: Just updated to 6.1.4. It's better. Wonder if it's the vw/vh support that's not fully functional (caniuse.com says it wasn't fully implented before 6.1)

Answer (score 0):

Should be, there's no reason why not. Percentage heights are very useful.

You need to add this to the image tag:

```
<img src="whatever.jpg" width="95%">
```

It can be any value, depending on how wide you want it. As long as you **make sure not to specify a height**, it will keep scale.

Your CSS should change to be more like this:

```
article {
  height:65%;
  max-height:65%;
  /* plus whatever else you want*/
}
```

As long as the parent is 100% window height, the article will be 65% window beight. Clearly if it's more, the article will be more.

The other solution is JavaScript. However, since you ask for CSS I'll omit that.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this? Can't seem to get it to work. height: 65% is not wanted btw. It should be able to be anything below 65% height of viewport, if the image is larger than it's shrunken to fit.

Comment: Can't get to foddle at the moment, I'm out in the middle of nowhere and SO is barely working. I'll make one soon. And yeah that was purely demonstrative. You can set height to whatever you want or leave it unset to make it variable

Comment: Also, this would be 65% of the image's parent; not the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
article{
    height:65%;
    max-height:65%;
    overflow:scroll; /* or hidden */
}

article .content > img{
    max-height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

JS Control (Because relative elements may not have a percentage height)

```
$(function(){
    var $article = $('article');
    var $height = $(window).height() * 0.65;
    $article.css({'height':$height+'px', 'max-height':$height+'px'});
});
```

Comment: OP asked specifically for pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should first set the 'inner' to 65% and then 'content' and image to 100% height. Like this,

```
.inner{
height:65%;
}

.content{
height:100%;
}

.content img{
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution using vanilla Javascript. Why have jQuery as a dependency unless you need to? (rhetorical).

```
var viewport = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("article");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(el, function(el) {
    el.style.maxHeight = Math.floor((viewport/100)*65)+"px";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PgtAY/